# Nested form validation in angular

Tags: angular

Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mh4cox?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

How do I properly show error messages on nested forms?
Validation works btw

I tried so many methods here without any luck.

I want it to show an error message on html using ngIF (... invalid && ... touched )

Constructor

```
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,private http:HttpClient,private requestService:RequestService) {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      id:[""],
      areaOfInterest: new FormControl("",Validators.required),
      status: new FormControl("",Validators.required),
      startDate: new FormControl("",Validators.required),
      endDate: new FormControl("",Validators.required),
      description: new FormControl("",Validators.required),
      notes: new FormControl("",Validators.required),
      createdBy:"",
      updatedBy:"",
      resourceDTOS: this.fb.array([]),
    });
    console.log(this.myForm);
    this.getOneRequest(localStorage.getItem('requestId'));
  }
```

This is the nested resource which is a FormArray in this case

```
addNewResourceDTOS() {
    this.control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.resourceDTOS;
    this.control.push(
        this.fb.group({
          seniority: this.fb.control(null,Validators.required),
          skillDTOS: this.fb.array([this.fb.group({
            skill: '' //i dont validate it here
          })]),
          resourceNotes: this.fb.control(null,Validators.required),
        })
    );
  }
```

The array skillDTOS

```
addNewResourceSkill(control) {
    control.push(
        this.fb.group({
          skill: new FormControl("",Validators.required),
        }))
  }
```

This is how I'm validating some of my main form variables

```
  get description() {
    return this.myForm.get('description');
  }
  get notes() {

    return this.myForm.get('notes');
  }
```

Example html "notes"

```
<small *ngIf="notes.invalid && notes.touched" class="text-danger">Please enter notes!</small>
```

It looks something like this

```
 data = {
    areaOfInterest:"",
    notes:"",

    resourceDTOS: [
      {
        seniority: "",
        skillDTOS: [
          {
            skill: "",
          }
        ],
        resourceNotes:""
      }
    ]
  }
```

Is it possible to validate at least seniority/resourceNotes  (or skill at best) as well?

Comment: Sorry, the description is not clear. From your code, I see that the validation works completely correctly. Validation works for the seniority, resourceNotes, and skill fields (excluding first skill).

Comment: But my goal is to show error message when invalid. Is it possible? Like with the main form variables such as description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, you can define a new method that would check a particular field's validity based on its and its ancestor indeces. Here's an example for the skill field:

#### `component.ts`

```js
  isSkillValid(resourceDTOSIndex: number, skillIndex: number): boolean {
    const resourceDTOSGroup = this.myForm.controls.resourceDTOS as FormGroup;
    const skillDTOSGroup =  resourceDTOSGroup.controls[resourceDTOSIndex] as FormGroup;
    const skillDTOS =  skillDTOSGroup.controls.skillDTOS as FormGroup;

    return skillDTOS.controls[skillIndex].valid;
  };
```

#### `component.html`

```html
<input
  formControlName="skill"
  class="form-control"
  style="margin-right:5px;"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Enter skill"
  id="skill"
  name="skill"
  aria-label="button1"
  aria-describedby="button1"
/>

<div *ngIf="!isSkillValid(i, j)">
  The skill field has no valid value
</div>
```

#### P.S.

I would really suggest you refactor the component and split it into smaller pieces since it's already hard to read and manipulate over it.

Comment: Note that this function will be called on each change detection and can affect performance. I'm especially careful with functions inside ngFor loops. Bumping into "infinite" loops (technically is not) sometimes, so just to be aware of the side effects of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply access validators with [`hasError()`](http://%3C!--%20language-all:%20lang-ts%20--%3E). So just target the formcontrol you want, usually accessed by `myFormgroup.get('formcontrolName')...` So in case of your iteration of `skill` you can access the current formcontrol from the defined `lines` you have declared for each loop:

```html
<div *ngFor="let lines of resource.get('skillDTOS').controls; let j=index">
  <div [formGroupName]="j">
    <input formControlName="skill"/>
    <div *ngIf="lines.get('skill').touched">
      <small *ngIf="lines.get('skill').hasError('required')">REQUIRED</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```